# HEADPHONES Don't work when change OS

Tags: headphones

I have both Operative systems, Windows and Ubuntu. When I turn my computer in windows and later I turn my computer in Ubuntu the headphones stop working. The headphones are detected but it appears that is muted.

I already checked in alsamixer if the channel is muted, but it is not.

Comment: Are you implying that it works if you don't boot to windows first?

Comment: yes, if i start my computer on Ubuntu, it works properly. When I start my computer on Windows, do something, and later change to Ubuntu, it stop working and I have to look for a temporary fix.